# Are there any modern alternatives of std::strchr() for C++?

Tags: c++, c-strings, strchr

I am extensively using `std::strchr()` in my code, but recently i started thinking about making my code more readable and modern. I wish there was function similar to `std::any_of/std::string::find_first_of` which is taking single character instead of containers. So i am questioning myself how to "update" my code to C++17.

```cpp
while (std::strchr("abcd", input) == nullptr) { //how to get rid of this C function?
        //do smth
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks, have a nice day!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no sense to update your code because the string literal has a type of a character array.

It would be a bad idea to create an intermediate object of for example std::string to perform such a simple task.

With c-strings declared like arrays use C string functions. C string functions are optimized and sometimes are performed by using just a pair of machine instructions.

With other containers use their member functions or standard algorithms.

Compare for example two approaches

```
const char *s = "abcd";

const char *p = strchr( s, c );

if ( p )
{
    //...
}
```

Or even like

```
const char *s = "abcd";

if ( const char *p = strchr( s, c ) )
{
    //...
}
```

and

```
const char *s = "abcd";
size_t n = std::strlen( s );

auto it = std::find( s, s + n, c );

if ( it != s + n )
{
    //...
}
```

Or less readable in C++ 17

```
const char *s = "abcd";
size_t n = std::strlen( s );

if ( auto it = std::find( s, s + n, c ); it != s + n )
{
    //...
}
```

It is evident that the first approach is more efficient.

On the other hand, if you have a general function that should accept c-strings 
 and/or objects of the type `std::string` then if the function does not change them then use `std::string_view` as a function parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::find` with a string, or `std::string`s very own [std::string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: Using `std::string_view` would be less wasteful.

Comment: @Deduplicator assuming OP starts with string literal, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you can store the C string in an array, you can use `std::find` like so:

```
constexpr char charset[] = "abcd";
while (std::find(std::begin(charset), std::end(charset), input) 
       == std::end(charset)) 
{...}
```

Comment: In general this approach is not suitable because the size of the array can be greater than the size of the stored string.

Comment: @vlad You mean if `charset[50] = "abcd"`? True but not sure if that case falls under things you need to take into account ... I could also say: in the general case (for huge arrays) this whole approach is bad, because it has linear runtime, better put your charset in a hashmap first and the lookup in the loop will be much faster.

Comment: Apart from this situation the program can deal with pointers to first characters of c-strings. In this case your approach is just invalid.

Comment: @vlad That's exactly why I included my first sentence, and also the first line of code. If you have your charsets as literals in the program, you can easily pull them out into arrays. Otherwise, it's not so simple.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the modern c++ alternative to `strchr` is [`std::char_traits<char>::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/find). It's also constexpr!

```
while (std::char_traits<char>::find("abcd", input) == nullptr) { //how to get rid of this C function?
    //do smth
}
```

However, I'm not sure that's any more readable than what you already have.
If your goal is purely readability, then there's nothing wrong with wrapping standard library functions with thin inline wrappers.

```
inline bool DoesStringContainSubstring(const char* str, const char* subStr) { return std::strchr(str, subStr) != nullptr; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::string`'s `find_first_of`. Example:

```
std::string string{"abcdefglrkemf..."};

while (string.find_first_of("def") != std::string::npos)
    //...
```

But if you don't want to create a new `std::string` object, `strstr` is the way to go. But note that this has a performance hit.

Comment: see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/. it accepts chars too.